# htaccess redirect multiple mobile pages multiple pages - redirects not working

Tags: .htaccess

What I'm trying to do is redirect pages to mobile pages. For example everything coming in through www.domain.com/* goes to one page and then anything coming into a specific page (or a couple) would go to another page.

I thought I had this figured out but over the course of testing, I was getting various issues and so I thought I would post my htaccess file and see where I'm overlooking.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule http://www.ourdomain.com/index.html http://www.ourdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule http://ourdomain.com/index.html http://www.ourdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule http://www.ourdomain.com/index.htm http://www.ourdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule http://ourdomain.com/index.htm http://www.ourdomain.com/ [L,R=301]

# This is where I have added code to redirect mobile users- not working
# Goal is anyone coming into all pages with the exception of the xselling
# and yselling pages needs to go to mobile_index. Mobile users coming in
# through xselling and yselling would go to mobile_index_sell.
# Side note we want PC and iPad users to go to non-mobile pages.
#
# Begin Mobile Page Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /mobile_index.html [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^xselling\.htm$ /mobile_index_sell.html [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^yselling\.htm$ /mobile_index_sell.html [L,R=302]
# END Mobile redirect

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.ourdomain.com/
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

Obviously, if you see anything else that would work better let me know. The htaccess itself has worked flawlessly for us with the exception of the mobile lines. Also, we tried PHP redirecting which also worked but it negatively impacted our Google Analytics and HitLinks.